# Separating SharePoint instance from Reporting Services (currently shared instance)

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services

Currently we are running SharePoint 2007 and Reporting Services on the same server.  Our reporting group would like to decouple this integrated environment.

I've found several sources on how to install both on the same server but none going the other way.

Does anyone have any information on how to go about splitting SRRS from SP?

Comment: Need a little more elaboration, are you backing out of SharePoint integrated mode entirely to native mode?  Or staying with integrated mode but want a server just for the reports?

Comment: Based on initial discussion I would say the plan is to back out of integrated mode entirely though at this point any information on either approach would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're backing into Native mode from SharePoint Integrated mode, I only see one possible way through this:

1. Setting up new Native RS Server

   Migrating each report one at a time, as no tools I know of exist to automate this kind of migration, this URL might be helpful too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh759331.aspx

You may be able to automate some of this, extracting reports from libraries and putting in Reporting Services via PowerShell, if you're up to it start building some custom scripts.

A lot of these reports may tie into data sources in SharePoint and would require some inspection before outright migration as they may not work on the other end.